# How to create a browser plug in?

Tags: javascript, plugins

I have to create a plug-in that will have to display information when user hovers over certain terms. Can anyone show me the direction how to do it?

I do not have much ideas about creating plug-ins. I know what i want to do can be done by java script. But can a java script file be installed as a browser plug in? any ideas on this will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is create a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/).  It's exactly what you're describing: a piece of javascript code installed in the browser as a plugin.

Userscripts are supported:

1. By Firefox using [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748)
2. By IE [with its own version of Greasemonkey](http://www.gm4ie.com/)
3. [Natively (soon) by Google Chrome](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts)
4. [Natively by Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/userjs/)
5. And even by [Safari](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/11/14/how-to-run-greasemonkey-scripts-in-safari/)

So support is on almost every major browser.

A userscript is the easiest solution for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Kango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561998/how-do-i-develop-browser-plugins-with-cross-platform-and-cross-browser-compatibi)'s Content Scripts are similar to userscripts, with perhaps [better support for all browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey#Compatibility), and the extension (and thus also the user script) can be [installed with one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382252/how-to-create-a-link-button-on-a-web-site-to-download-and-install-browser-extens) if self-hosted instead of installing Greasemonkey separately.