# How do I develop browser plugins with cross-platform and cross-browser compatibility in mind?

Tags: cross-browser, cross-platform, activex, webbrowser-control, browser-plugin

My company currently has a product which relies on a custom, in-house ActiveX control. The technology it employs is itself cross-platform by design, but our solution is obviously limited to Internet Explorer on Windows.

Long term we would like to become cross-browser and cross-platform (i.e., support other browsers on Windows, support the Macintosh or Linux).

Obviously if we wanted to support Firefox on Windows I would need to write a plugin for it. But if we wanted to support the Macintosh, how do I attack that? Is it possible to compile a version of the Firefox plugin that runs on the Mac? Would I be remiss to not also support Safari on the Mac? Are there any plugins which are cross-browser on a platform? (i.e., can any browsers run plugins for other browsers)

What do people generally do when they want to support multiple platforms with a process that will need to be cross-platform and cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is [firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org)

Comment: Edited your post to post to http://www.firebreath.org instead of the google code page; we don't use that anymore =]

Answer (score 7):

You could also try [kango](http://kangoextensions.com/)

Comment: kango looks interesting, but it is for extensions, not plugins.  see http://npapi.com/extensions

Comment: @taxilian I think the OP wants extension

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) is a good choice for you! I just compile a test plugin on vs2010 and it's compatible with IE9, Firefox and google chrome.

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with FireBreath?

Comment: I am a newbie to FireBreath now. But I think it's a amazing tool to create a plugin.

Comment: it is portable to Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Java with native libraries. Long time age I've seen video chat developed in such way. Applet included native code for every supported platform. I'm not a java programmer, I can't tell you details, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

use COM on Windows and XPCOM/Corba in Firefox/Linux.

Comment: OS X is also just a Unix, so XPCOM should do it there, too.

Comment: XPCOM isn't supported for creating browser plugins in Firefox anymore, and on windows COM would only work on IE. On all platforms, XPCOM would only help on Firefox even back when it was supported for plugins. (note, I realize that it can still be used for extensions)