# Browser plugin for cross-domain iframe communication

Tags: plugins, browser, iframe, cross-domain

I would like to create a browser plugin/extension that would allow the browser to read contents of a cross-domain iframe.  I understand that this isn't possible with javascript, but perhaps someone could point me in the right direction of how to create a plugin that users could install.  A cross-browser solution would be ideal.

Specifically, I am creating helpful navigation utility, and I want to know the url of the iframe so that I can prevent the iframe from navigating to any questionable sites accidentally.  I would also like to detect the size of the contents.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/ This is what I use.

Comment: I don't own the iframe contents, so I can't add any special postmessage code to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: file_get_contents:** 
What you can try is to get the contents from the page by the PHP function `file_get_contents`, load the CSS files and get the contents and the size of the page.

**Option 2: Headers:** 
You can start here: http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html
See the "allow-access-from" section where you can allow domains to be accessed cross domain when they have specific headers.

Comment: I believe that a parent web page can't access anything in the iframe, including the URL.  If I don't know the URL, I can't use file_get_contents.  I also don't own the iframe contents to allow for option 2 to be used.

Comment: Then I don't think there is anything you can do? Since you can't grant yourself access to the page.

Answer (score 0):

[Userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688002/how-to-create-a-browser-plug-in) have cross-domain XMLHttpRequest, and they will even run on all browsers. They (or at least Kango's Content Scripts) have the ability to write and read stored values for cross-window communication.