# How to create a link/button on a web-site to download and install browser extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm creating a web-site for a company which has browser extensions for Google Chrome, FireFox and Opera. And there's a page from where the site users are intended to download and install those extensions. However I'm not sure how this should technically work. What kind of links/buttons should I create for the users to download those extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to host the crx yourself you should look at these two links....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html

If your going to use the Web Store to host your extension then you should look at this link....
http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/inline_installation.html