# Cross domain Post method ajax call using jQuery with XML response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I want to send a ajax request using post method with the XML as a response text, Is it possible, If it is possible please let me know the possible way for it.

For Ex

```
url : "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate"
data : {FromCurrency:"INR",ToCurrency:"AUD"}
method : GET or POST
```

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=AUD

I need the response of this URL using ajax.

Comment: If they support `JSONP`, you can add that switch. You have to learn how to do it, though. This [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) isn't too bad.

Comment: Actually, you'd probably want [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) if that site doesn't have a `JSONP` feed. Of course, the browser has to support it too.

Comment: Without JSONP cant we render the content using some other methods??

Comment: `CORS`. Or a server-routed proxy using cURL or something. It's a same-origin issue; there's only a few ways around it.

Comment: can also use a 3rd party proxy like Yahoo YQL. Can get a jsonp url set up in minutes in YQL console

Comment: Yup , Even I am also thinking of it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/),

```
var url = 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=INR&ToCurrency=AUD'; // website you want to scrape
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';  
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){  
    if(data.query.results){
        var result = data.query.results.double.content.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: security measure...If you are appending result in your dom and if it involves `<script></script>` tags. I do not know regex myself but it has been copied from some place in internet :)

Comment: +1  yeah..I thought about it after...never used it but looks like good idea to implement...always

Comment: Never knew about YQL as proxy for the same domain policy. Now I know. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own script on server on the same domain that does request to the webservicex.net and returns data in any format that you want.

So, ajax request -> your server (on the same domain) -> webservicex.net

Answer (score 0):

It seems that server does not support CORS. Then you won't be able to do this with an ajax call due to the `same origin policy`