# Http get in to external url

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I have to make a function that have to make a get into a public url, it will return me a plain text wich.

Depending on that i will make a validation.

I try to make it with the dojo ajax get method but since is a different domain it will not work ( only on Explorer).

How I can make that call to the external domain  and manage the answer.

the url will be something like this.

```
http://my.socket:8080/?option1=1&option2=2
```

It can be with ajax or just a java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is working on client side which means you are not able to make foreign domain ajax calls 
due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

it will be good technique if you write that GET call in your applications server side 
and make ajax call to your application which will act as gateway and fetch data from remote server

Comment: Sounds goods, any Idea of how I manage the text that i Recieve from the url  in my server side.    I can make something like this to ho hit the external url , but how i manage the asnwer.  URL url = new URL("http://socket.");
          URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoOutput(true);
        
         
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ) );
        
          in.close();

Comment: basically you need to write code which will be executed when you navigate to 
yourdomain.com/gatewaycode/maybemoreparams
and will print data returned by foreign domain
if you'll manage that then you'll make ajax call to yourdomain.com/gatewaycode/maybemoreparams

am i missing something from your question ?
you're using java on your server side ?

Comment: yes the application is in java, I like the idea that make the call in my server side and then with ajax call my same domain, What I,m not sure is how to make the call from my server side.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359689/how-to-send-http-request-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Due to same origin policy, you cannot do simple ajax calls across cross domains.

You can ajax call your own server page which resides on same domain and that page can do HTTP get and get the content for you.

or you can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

```
var url = 'http://my.socket:8080/?option1=1&option2=2'; // website you want to scrape
var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + url + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';  
$.getJSON(yql,function(data){  
    if(data.query.results){
        var result = data.query.results.double.content.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239584/cross-domain-post-method-ajax-call-using-jquery-with-xml-response/11240217#11240217)

Comment: I dont know about plain text ( you can filter at your end though ) but you can get xml. Just change this line `select * from html....` to `select * from xml....`