# enable XSS in chrome and/or safari

Tags: google-chrome, xss

I'm developing a native iOs app using cordova to do the native stuff, so I can focus on html/javascript and css. However, I need to make cross-domain ajax calls, which is fine in my native app, but not when I run my project in Chrome. So I would like to disable this security feature in Chrome so I can test my app. Is there an easy way to do this ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are developing an iOS app I assume you are on OSX in which case you can essentially launch Chrome with XXS enabled be executing the following command line:

open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security

In fact, I use it so often I added an alias in my .bash_profile:

alias chrometest='open -a "Google Chrome" --args --disable-web-security'

This has been working for me for quite some time all the way up to my current version of Chrome: 38.0.2125.104

Of course you can name it whatever you like…good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do **[jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)**  for your cross domain requests.

Or another trick is modifying the server headers to allow cross site ajax.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

From [cors](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: I don't have control over the remote server which I'm trying to call cross-domain! ( and JSONP is not supported )

Comment: Hum, according to http://enable-cors.org/client.html  , it should work,  have you tried  the testclient ?  http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client