# Get list of data- attribute values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I am trying to capture all of the values for the `data-hiringurl` attributes on this page http://wearemadeinny.com/find-a-job/.

I tried `var data = $("li").attr('data-hiringurl');` and `var data = $("li").data('hiringurl');` in console, but got this `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

All of the data attributes are in `<li>` elements, but they do not have a common id.

Comment: if you can try to post the codes related to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this since the content is coming via an iframe of another domain http://mappedinny.com/

```
<iframe src="http://mappedinny.com/" height="900" width="100%%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is the error you should be getting when you try to access

```
$('iframe').contents().find('li[data-hiringurl]').val()
SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://wearemadeinny.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

***Update:***

If this for your own web-scraping purpose try disabling same origin policy in your browser configuration. Here are the links which will help you to disable same origin policy

Chrome: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Firefox: [Disable firefox same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var data = $("li[data-hiringurl]");
```

Comment: Still getting this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: That error is coming from other part of your code. Please check again.