# How to disable The Same Origin Policy in Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

How can I disable **The Same Origin Policy** in Firefox Developer Edition. For Some reason I thought it should be easy to do this in Developer Edition but I can't find the settings.

Comment: I do not think this is the right site to ask this because it has nothing to do with programming. Move it into the appropriate site if you want to save yourself from severe downvote :)

Comment: @Begueradj How this has nothing to do with programming? I need to disable this policy to test my *code*. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) are in this website.

Answer (score -5):

Honestly you shouldn't be able to do that in any browser - the service should send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or similar if it can be used cross-domain. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers

Maybe if you need to test the service before those headers are implemented you could set it to use a local proxy that adds the headers.

Comment: This is a non-answer. It is possible to do this in other browsers and there are good use cases for it.

Comment: Really? In what browser? I hadn't heard of that being allowed except for when using CORS headers.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: @Mohsen Interesting! I didn't know that