# Getting an error response for angular HTTP on XML feed

Tags: android, angularjs, xml, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get headlines from yahoo finance and the following code doesn't seem to work. It goes straight to the error handler. I tried a few other URL's and they don't seem to work either. I tested this code within the android emulator with ionic. What am I doing wrong?

```
$http.get("http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=GOOG&region=US&lang=en-US")
    .success(function(data) {
        $log.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        $log.log("ERROR: " + data);
});
```

UPDATE: 
Read through Mitch's links, you'll very likely find a solution there like I did. For me I had to use the `--disable-web-security` when starting chromium. Apparently the [allow origin plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) isn't enough for these types of http request's.

Also, if you're having trouble in the emulator don't use live reload. That seems to cause a problem with http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your developer console, you will see this message : `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

It means that the response received does allow requests from localhost, so your browser blocks it. Javascript is limited by the "same origin policy" for security reasons so that a malicious script cannot contact a remote server and send sensitive data. More details on this kind of problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311585/2298988

This only happens because you're testing your application in a browser though. **If you build your Ionic app and test it on a device, it should work perfectly**.

To test your app in a browser, you have to **disable web security**. Which you should do **only for development purposes**, never when surfing.

Here is a post explaining how to disable web security in Chrome: 
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

It seems there is a plugin doing it for Firefox, but I haven't tried it:
[Disable firefox same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had this covered when I used the same origin extension but apparently I still needed to include the the flag --disable-web-security on startup.

Comment: Also you say if I build it and test on a device it'll work. But does that mean it can't work in an emulator?

Comment: It should work in an emulator as well. This security comes from the browser. On Cordova, it's handled by the whitelist plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: I already had the whitelist plugin installed but it appears to be a problem with livereload in the emulator. If you turn livereload off it seems to work. Thank's again.