# User must have CORS enabled how to prevent that.

Tags: http, elasticsearch, cors

I have made a single page web application that utilizes elasticsearch and requires that the user have CORS enabled and I was wondering what I could do to make the web application not require that the user have CORS enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Every current browser forces the CORS verification, and they cannot be disabled on the level of a single website.

You need to add `Access-Control-*` headers which inform your browser it can make a safe connection.

**1. If you are making connections directly to the ElasticSearch:**

You will need to modify your `elasticsearch.yml` file. Add keys below to the configuration file and restart your server:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
```

These keys enable sending proper headers to the client and allow browsers to establish connections. Remember to change the `http.cors.allow-origin` regex to be valid with your domain if you run the server outside localhost.

More details and additional settings you can find in [ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2)

**2. If you are using reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx)**

You can also add the required headers on the reverse proxy level. Unlike the previous method, in this case, you need to set all the necessary headers by yourself to make the connection happen.

Basic configuration for Nginx server used as the reverse proxy:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name elasticsearch.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
        proxy_add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://example.com';
        proxy_add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE';
        proxy_add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length';
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            return 200;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want (e.g. for development purposes) to disable CORS validation on your browser, you can also do it. However, before you do that, please be aware of all the risks.

## Disabling CORS checking in Google Chrome:

You need to run Google Chrome with the following arguments: `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`.

#### Windows and Linux users

```
$ [Chrome executable path] --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

#### Mac OS users

```
$ open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

## Disabling CORS checking in Safari:

1. Enable Safari Developer Menu

   Go to *Safari* -> *Preferences* -> *Advanced* and select *Show Developer Menu in menu bar*
2. Open Developer menu in menu bar
3. Select *Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions*

## Disabling CORS checking in Firefox

Check [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29096229/5508582)

Comment: I'm still having the same issue after modifying the elasticsearch file. I can get it to work on my local network, but not outside of my local network. I'm using a simple node http-server with cors enabled.

Comment: @CamiloRiviere did you modified the `http.cors.allow-origin` to match origins outside your local machine?

Comment: I followed the regex you posted above. "/https?:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]+)?/" and even removed "localhost" from the regex to see if that work, but it didn't. Is there a different regex that I need to use to able to connect from a remote machine?

Comment: @CamiloRiviere You need to provide a regex that allows your remote domain to connect. For example, if you have a domain `example.com`, you'll need to set the `http.cors.allow-origin` to `/https?:\/\/(?:.+\.)?example.com(:[0-9]+)?/` which will allow to connect from `example.com` domain and all its subdomains from any port (e.g. `http://example.com` and `https://test.example.com:8080`)

Comment: Ah, I see. So this would be easier if I actually host this web application somewhere then?