# Disable Firefox Same Origin Policy without installing a plugin

Tags: firefox, cors, same-origin-policy

Is there a way to disable the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) on the Mozilla Firefox browser **by toggling a flag in the browser**?

This is strictly for development, for not production use.

---

Please note:

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy) asked 3+ years ago yielded an accepted answer that recommends users to install a plugin. I consider this less secure and more cumbersome than toggling a flag (e.g. in the about:config, or passing a parameter when starting the browser [like in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)).

Comment: I see this got downvoted. Could I receive some feedback as to what the problem is with this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After having tried to find a Firefox setting for various hours, and after having opened a bounty, I think the right answer to this question is:

**At the moment of writing (March 2018), it is not possible to disable the same policy origin in Firefox by simply setting a flag.**

I would personally recommend people to use Chrome instead for this kind of work, because disabling this setting [is very easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome), quick and doesn't involve installing third-party software.

Comment: Useful information. Does you have some documentation about it?

Comment: Bug report can be seen here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1039678

Was opened 6 years ago and the general consensus is that it is wanted and needed in Firefox but needs to be presented in a clear and usable way, there is resistance to make it a command line flag as the developers appear to feel this is not clear enough.

Comment: You may be able to by compiling your own version, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35760327/109458 though I haven't yet verified this as of today, I might try to do this for some experimentation

Answer (score 14):

There is a boolean in Mozilla Firefox that *should* allow toggling of the same origin policy called `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy`.

Go to `about:config` in your browser and accept the risk:

[image]

Then search for `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` and double click it to toggle it to `false` like so:

[image]

I have not tested this but in my experience, this is the flag controlling the same origin policy.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. From the manual, if this flag is set to true, then: `Local documents have access to other local documents in the same directory and in subdirectories, but not directory listings`. See: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy

Answer (score 6):

*Rather than directly answer your question, this alternative might be viable if you also have ownership of the server*

Get your server to add the following response header. (+ Apply a DevOps process or piece of code to ensure only apply this code during development)

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

.. With the value of your origin domain, e.g.
`http://example.com` or alternatively `*` for all domains.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to be modifying the server, I'm looking for a solution similar to what Chrome offers, thanks.

Comment: doesn't work. My browser isn't even sending requests to the desired server because it throws a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` before the request is even sent, so changing the server won't help.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont hace access to server resources. That's why most of us are looking for a way to disable CORS policy.

Answer (score -3):

So I wasn't able to do this using Firefox. I was able to do this inside of chrome using the following. My purpose was for testing endpoint access to a server without CORS being setup.

```
google-chrome disable-web-security -allow-file-access-from-files — allow-file-access
```

Your google chrome executable can vary to whatever you have linked it to.

Source: https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/disable-cross-origin-on-chrome-for-localhost-c644b131db19