# Getting different server response in Jquery $ajax and fetch in reactjs. Why aren't they the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, fetch-api

$ajax server response:

```
{"username":"","password":""}
```

fetch server response:

```
{"{\"username\":\"\",\"password\":\"\"}":""}
```

Why aren't they the same? I need the same server response. I'm using PHP+Apache

Here is my code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export function FetchData(type, data){

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost/oms/'+ type + ".php";

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serverUrl,
            data //body : {username: "username", password:"password"}
         })
        .done(function(res) {
            //console.log(res);
            resolve (res);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, exception){
            //alert('server error()');
            reject(jqXHR);
        });

    fetch(serverUrl,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE',
            //'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Accept',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
        //body : {username: data.username, password: data.password}
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        resolve(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       reject(error);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The responses are essentially the same just that response from fetch library returns a Stringified JSON.
You need to convert it into actual JS object.

`const responseData = JSON.parse(response.json())`

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you're sending the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with `JSON` data you need to change it to `application/json` like

```
export const FetchData = (type, data) => {
    let serverUrl = 'http://localhost/oms/'+ type + ".php";
    let data = {
        username: data.username,
        password: data.password
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(serverUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                resolve(responseJson)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error)
            })

    })
};
```

I added `credentials` it's read-only property of the Request interface indicates whether the user agent should send cookies from the other domain in the case of cross-origin requests. This is similar to XHR’s withCredentials flag

If you want to use something smaller to jQuery you can use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) It's XMLHttpRequests

If you get some CORS issues [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940347/is-there-any-alternative-to-cors-google-chrome-extension-how-to-make-successful/48940976#48940976) will help you

Comment: Thanks @Liam for answering...I've tried...but i'm getting [ ] server reply now...please help..

Comment: Do you mean you're getting response empty or that's an error?

Comment: Well, do you getting response if you used content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` try to send it with no headers or add mode: "no-cors",

Comment: when I set type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded ...and mode to "no-cors" at the same time...I used to get the $_POST data....@Liam

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code, I guess because I added credentials 
 try to remove it if this wont work consider asking this another question

Comment: Consider asking this issue in another question