# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with Flask when using BasicAuth

Tags: python, flask-login, flask-cors

I have a Flask application containing various images displaying some clusters constructed by a K-Means algorithm. 
The user should be able to select one or several images and afterwards get redirected to a web-page where the clusters can be further assessed. 
The application worked as intended until I added basic access authentication.

Specifically, my (simplified) python script goes as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for 
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_basicauth import BasicAuth

app=Flask(__name__)

app.config['BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'] = os.environ['AUTH_USERNAME']
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD'] = os.environ['AUTH_PASSWORD']
app.config['BASIC_AUTH_FORCE']= True
basic_auth=BasicAuth(app)

CORS(app)


@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    images=os.listdir(app.root_path+"/static/img/")
    return render_template("cluster_images.html", cluster_images = images)

@app.route("/filter", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def filter():
if request.method=="POST":
    sel=request.get_json()

#Do some operations with sel
```

The problem appears when I try to redirect to the /filter route from the main route which is done by "btn1". 
The following shows the function from "cluster_images.html" taking care the http request when btn1 is fired

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.loader')},
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url:  "http://localhost:5000/filter",
        dataType : 'html',
        data : JSON.stringify(images), success: function(){window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/filter"}
})
})
})
```

When I press the button I get the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/filter. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).[Learn More]

Comment: Did you try setting `crossDomain: true` in the ajax?

Comment: Try this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940347/is-there-any-alternative-to-cors-google-chrome-extension-how-to-make-successful

Comment: The first one did not work.
For the second one I have to change my request from ajax to simple jQuery?