# How to avoid CORS errors ("Failed to fetch" or "Server not found or an error occurred") when making requests from Swagger Editor?

Tags: cors, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I have the following OpenAPI definition:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple API
  description: A simple API to learn how to write OpenAPI Specification

schemes:
  - https
host: now.httpbin.org
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Get date in rfc2822 format
      responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: object
            items:
              properties:
                now:
                  type: object
                    rfc2822:
                      type: string
```

I would like to retrieve `rfc2822` from the [response](https://now.httpbin.org/):

```
{"now": {"epoch": 1531932335.0632613, "slang_date": "today", "slang_time": "now", "iso8601": "2018-07-18T16:45:35.063261Z", "rfc2822": "Wed, 18 Jul 2018 16:45:35 GMT", "rfc3339": "2018-07-18T16:45:35.06Z"}, "urls": ["/", "/docs", "/when/:human-timestamp", "/parse/:machine-timestamp"]}
```

But when I make a request from Swagger Editor, I get an error:

> ERROR Server not found or an error occurred

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What tool do you use to send the request?

Comment: local swagger editor from the browser

Comment: What is the error message in the browser console?

Comment: @Helen, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.` Can I fix it somehow or play with swagger & `now.httpbin.org` from another place?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.

This is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. The server at https://now.httpbin.org does not support CORS, so the browsers won't let web pages served from other domains to make requests to now.httpbin.org from JavaScript.

You have a few options:

- Ask the owners of https://now.httpbin.org to [support CORS](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).

  **Note:** The server must not require authentication for preflight `OPTIONS` requests. `OPTIONS` requests should return 200 with the proper CORS headers.
- If you are the owner - consider hosting Swagger UI on the same server and port (now.httpbin.org:443) to avoid CORS altogether.
- Disable CORS restrictions in your browser. **This reduces browser security so only do this if you understand the risks.**

  - [Bypass CORS in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/113116)
  - [Bypass CORS in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17088609/113116)
- Use [SwaggerHub](https://app.swaggerhub.com) instead of Swagger Editor to edit and test your API definitions. SwaggerHub proxies "try it out" requests through its servers so it's not subject to CORS restrictions. *(Disclosure: I work for the company that makes SwaggerHub.)*

By the way, your response definition is not valid. The response is missing a `description` and the `schema` is wrong (e.g. has an extra `items` keyword). It should be:

```yaml
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              now:
                type: object
                properties:
                  rfc2822:
                    type: string
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I sent an OAuth2 request to Keycloak and received this error message.

I resolved this issue by setting '*' in the "Web Origins" field in the Keycloak client options.