# How to proxy requests in docker swagger ui

Tags: docker, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger UI using its docker version. The `Try it out` button is not working as expected from the Web UI because there's a problem with cors. I'm running the UI from `localhost` and doing requests to another domain. I have read this other question [How to avoid CORS errors ("Failed to fetch" or "Server not found or an error occurred") when making requests from Swagger Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407341/how-to-avoid-cors-errors-failed-to-fetch-or-server-not-found-or-an-error-occ) but I cannot do any of the solutions it says.

I'm not sure if it's posible to setup a proxy on the docker container as SwaggerHub does, like, instead of the `Try it out` request be resolved on the browser, resolve it on the docker container.

Do you know if that is posible?