# How can I upload CSV File in React with backend in Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

So I made this app which takes a CSV file from the frontend, sends it to backend written in flask. The backend uses data from the CSV file and generates a new table which it then sends to the jinja template in the form of a list. The list is then displayed in the form of a Bootstrap table.
I want to make the frontend using React which does the same functionalities. But since I am a newbie in React, I can see no lead forward.
Following is my Flask code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.jsx")


@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            file = request.form["upload-file"]
            if file == False:
                return
            data = pd.read_excel(file)
            arr = np.array(data)
            N = arr[2][0]
            N = int(N[2:])
            col = []
            stu = []
            for i in range(N):
                col.append(arr[0][i])
            for i in range(N):
                stu.append(arr[1][i])
            college = []
            student = []
            # college array
            for i in range(4, 4 + N):
                tmp = []
                for j in range(0, N):
                    x = stu.index(arr[i][j + 1])
                    tmp.append(x + N)
                college.append(tmp)
            # student array
            for i in range(5 + N, 5 + (2 * N)):
                tmp = []
                for j in range(0, N):
                    x = col.index(arr[i][j + 1])
                    tmp.append(x)
                student.append(tmp)

            ans = []
            prefer = []
            for i in range(0, len(college)):
                prefer.append(college[i])
            for i in range(0, len(student)):
                prefer.append(student[i])

            def sPrefersC1OverC(prefer, s, c, c1):
                for i in range(N):
                    if prefer[s][i] == c1:
                        return True
                    if prefer[s][i] == c:
                        return False

            def stablMatch(prefer):
                sPartner = [-1 for i in range(N)]
                cFree = [False for i in range(N)]
                freeCount = N
                while freeCount > 0:
                    c = 0
                    while c < N:
                        if cFree[c] == False:
                            break
                        c += 1
                    i = 0
                    while i < N and cFree[c] == False:
                        s = prefer[c][i]
                        if sPartner[s - N] == -1:
                            sPartner[s - N] = c
                            cFree[c] = True
                            freeCount -= 1
                        else:
                            c1 = sPartner[s - N]
                            if sPrefersC1OverC(prefer, s, c, c1) == False:
                                sPartner[s - N] = c
                                cFree[c] = True
                                cFree[c1] = False
                        i += 1
                for i in range(N):
                    tmp = []
                    tmp.append(stu[((i + N) % N)])
                    tmp.append(col[sPartner[i]])
                    ans.append(tmp)

            stablMatch(prefer)

            return render_template("data.jsx", N=N, ans=ans,)
    except:
        return render_template("error.jsx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the React code which I tried but it failed

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form extends Component {
  onChange(e) {
    let file = e.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const url = "http://localhost:3000/data";
      const formData = { file: e.target.result };
      return postMessage(url, formData).then((response) =>
        console.warn("result!!", response)
      );
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form action="data" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group m-2">
            <input
              type="file"
              name="upload-file"
              class="form-control-file"
              id="exampleFormControlFile1"
            />
            <button
              type="submit"
              onClick={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
              class="btn btn-outline-dark m-2"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

The frontend is unable to POST the file to the backend

I tried to find online solutions but none of them could really be the solution to my problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: " .. it failed", how do you know? A stacktrace would be really helpful.

Comment: "Proxy error: Could not proxy request /data from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)."
This is the error that I get every time I make the post request.
I'm sorry if this is not what you were asking for.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29096229/6741053, https://medium.com/excited-developers/file-upload-with-react-flask-e115e6f2bf99 .... I feel its the browser denying cross origin requests. You can quickly verify by enabling CORS requests through an extension. Feel free to answer your question if the links provided solve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845455/6741053, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Comment: Cheers, glad it worked. Feel free to write a good answer explaining how you solved it and accept it, so that it will help others in future.